# How to/can I get an OOB error for a whole forest witht he randomForest package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, random-forest

I have a substantially sized dataset with different levels of missingness per variable. I want to run random forests on different combinations of this dataset based on missingness and then so a sensitivity analysis of OOB error to missingness threshold. How can I get the OOB error for a whole forest?

Comment: If you are doing classification, you might look at the err.rate vector. According to the documentation, the final value will be the OOB error for the whole forest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Imo answerd with the following:

"If you are doing classification, you might look at the err.rate vector. According to the documentation, the final value will be the OOB error for the whole forest"